# Validates_uniqueness_of does not work when doing a large Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, transactions

I have a validate_uniqueness_of :field inside my ActiveRecord model. When i do a single create/update it works nicely but i have to do some large batch creation from csv files inside a Transaction
When i am in the transaction the validate_uniqueness_of does not detect the error and the model is saved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that the non-unique values are created during the transaction?

The validate methods check before the transaction and then all values are still not present in the table and thus unique.

**Edit:** Create a index with the unique property turned on for your field and the transaction will fail and thus preventing the addition of non-unique elements.
To do some you should add something this in your migration file

```
add_index("tablename", "fieldname", { :name => "fieldname_index", :unique => true })
```

**Edit 2:** A transaction like this will will give something like a "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '123' for key 1: <sql statement here>" error.

```
Table.transaction do
  i1 = Table.new
  i1.fieldname = "123"
  i1.save
  i2 = Table.new
  i2.fieldname = "123"
  i2.save
end
```

Comment: what kind of database are you using. I just tried to add same values to a unique field using a transaction and I got an error (using MYSQL)

Comment: 5.1 when i do plain insert in the db shell mysql gives the error as expected

Answer (score 0):

validates_uniqueness_of is subject to race conditions, and you still need to have the appropriate unique constraints on your database. You are describing [this situation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of). The link provides a few solutions.

Comment: i am already using the :unique => true in for the field that should be unique but to no luck inside the transaction (it works if i do a simple sql insert in command line)